# SAS outer union corr BY using Do Loop

Tags: sas

I need to find a way to use loop to union my datasets.
For example, I have three tables with different column names. I want to union them all by using "outer nuion corr".
The code like this:

```
     proc sql;
         create table new as
         select * from a1
         outer union corr
         select * from b1
         outer union corr
         select * from c1   ;
    quit;
```

I want to use the loop function to do these unions.

```
%macro union_a;
  proc sql;
   create table new as
    select * from a1
        %do i = 2 %to 3;
        outer union corr select * from a&i 
        ;
    quit;

 %end;
%mend;
%union_a;
```

it gives me an error:

```
NOTE: Line generated by the invoked macro "UNION_A".
5             outer union corr select * from a&i         ;
              -----
              180

ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

How should I do this? Thank you!

JH

Comment: usually a problem of semi-colon generated in your macro. Why not a simple data step?

Comment: Do you have a  naming convention for your data sets? If you do, a SET or APPEND would be more efficient here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `%end;` statement is in the wrong place.

```
%macro union_a;
  %local i;
  proc sql;
    create table new as
      select * from a1
  %do i = 2 %to 3;
        outer union corr select * from a&i 
  %end;
    ;
  quit;
%mend;
```

Indentation can help make this clearer.  It also helps to indent the macro code independent of the indentation of the SAS code that it is generating.

Also why not just use a DATA step?

```
data new ;
  set a1-a3 ;
run;
```